# Como puedo verificar si una base de datos MySQL determinada existe desde Java?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

Quiero verificar si mi base de datos existe antes de continuar con la execucion de mi programa, mas no se por donde comenzar, pues he mirado algunos ejemplos y no me ha funcionado nada.

Esta es la consulta que desea tirar:

```
"SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'Data_base'"
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy abierta, es decir, tiene mucahs respuestas con lo que has aportado. Podrías indicarnos que estas usando para la conexion con la base de datos? has creado alguna clase conexion? y si puedes compartir el código del mismo.

Comment: ¿Qué tal usar la estrategia de que la creas solo si no existe? Esto se logra ejecutando lo sgte: `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mibd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despues de investiar y unas cuantas pruebas encontre la solución, cree esta funcion para verificar si existe, utilizando el driver jdbc:

```
public boolean dbExists(String puerto, String db, String pass) {
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement st = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + puerto + "/" + db, "root", pass);
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '" + db + "'";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main, "La base de datos existe.");
                exist = true;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main, "La base de datos no existe.");
            exist = false;
        }
        return exist;
    }
```

Espero les sea de ayuda en caso de que busquen algo similar

Answer (score 1):

Habiendo hecho antes una conexión a alguna otra base y haciendo:

```
private static void 
  existeBaseDatos(String nom) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("show databases");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {                
            if (rs.getString(1).equals(nom)) {
                System.out.println("Si que existe la BD: "+nom);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No existe esa base de datos");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la consulta show databases con like:

```
String sql = "show databases  like '" + db + "'";
```

Y verifica si la consulta devuelve un resultado.